# react-native firebase get array of keys using async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the keys of a children of a specified record using `async/await` but it doesn't seem to work, I keep getting unhandled promise rejection. I am trying to loop through the snapshot and get the key of every child and store them in an array

Here is what I've tried:

```
await firebase.database().ref('User-Message/' + this.state.user.id).once('value', async (snapshot) => {
  await snapshot.forEach(user => {
    this.list.push(user.key)
  })
  return key;
})
```

I also tried this way:

```
let db = await firebase.database().ref('User-Message').child(this.state.user.id);

let response = await db.once('value');

let users = await response.forEach(user => {
  console.log(user.key);
  return user.key;
})
```

How can I get an array of the keys using `async/await`?

here is the error i keep getting

```
Possible Unhandled Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this.list.push()')
```

Comment: `await`ing a `forEach` doesn't make any sense, because `forEach` returns `undefined`, which is not a `Promise`. `i keep getting unhandled promise rejection` What error, exactly?

Comment: i tried removing await from foreach .. still the same log of the `unhandled promise rejection` ..

Comment: Yes, so what is that error, exactly? Without knowing what the error is, it's pretty hard to fix it

Comment: hold on i'll edit the question and add the error

Comment: check the error in the question

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Do you want `this.list` to become an array of the user keys that have just been retrieved?

Comment: yes i want to push the array to a this.list so i can fetch the whole user from my backend and display a list of users

Answer (score 0):

Check the `list` variable. is it an array?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* let users = await response.forEach(user => {
  console.log(user.key);
  return user.key;
})
// YOUR CODE
*/


//you can do in this way

response =[
  {key:123, name:"Overflow"},
  {key:456, name:"Stack"},
]
let userKeys = response.map(user => user.key)
console.log("userKeys", userKeys)
```